# compilation error under gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

i got a compilation error grom gcc (versions less than 6). clang and vc2013/2015 and gcc6 do not complain about this code. So i think this it is a bug of gcc 4.x-5.x.
is there any workaround to make this code compile on gcc 4.x-5.x?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
using namespace std;

template <typename... ParamTypes> 
void CreateObject(ParamTypes... args)
{
// error: conversion from 'std::tuple<std::type_index, std::type_index, std::type_index>' to non-scalar type 'std::tuple<std::type_index>' requested
    auto types = make_tuple(type_index(typeid(args))...);
}

int main()
{
    CreateObject(1, "2", 1.1f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you set `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: It's not good practice to start your function names with a capital letter

Comment: @Mackiavelli care to expand on that?

Comment: The naming convention states that identifiers starting with a capital letter are either constants (all uppercase) or class names (camel-case)

Comment: @TartanLlama General convention is that leading capital letter signifies a type.

Comment: @Mackiavelli That's in no way universally accepted. I know several coding styles which use PascalCase for functions. There is no universal naming convention in C++.

Comment: And you'll get bashed when you switch companies because that's extremely rare. Every big company uses this convention and it's universal across most similar languages, example: Java

Comment: What naming convention? The Google style guide uses capital letters to begin functions, for example, and that's pretty widely used. C++ is not Java.

Comment: Great discussion here! What is about the OP question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TartanLlama: The google C++ style guide is not widely used (its not considered that good (or was not the last time I looked several years ago) it is good for google to keep code compatible with legacy code).

Comment: @Mackiavelli: I personally agree. **But** universal is a bit strong.

Comment: Well if someone goes through an API and sees a capital case method, they will (at first) think that it's a constructor and be a bit confused. Why cause the mayhem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like bug in gcc, but you can just write function, that returns `type_index` as a workaround.

```
template<typename T>
type_index get_index(const T& v)
{
   return type_index(typeid(v));
}

template <typename... ParamTypes> 
void CreateObject(ParamTypes... args)
{
    auto types = make_tuple(get_index(args)...);
}
```

or you can just not to use `auto`

```
template <typename... ParamTypes> 
void CreateObject(ParamTypes... args)
{
    tuple<type_index, type_index, type_index> types =
    make_tuple(typeindex(typeid(args))...);
}
```

Comment: thanks - i did not think of additional function.
i need auto because CreateObject is used for the different number of arguments